# Volley and Robolectric 3.0

Tags: android, android-volley, robolectric

I would like to ask if there is a any good tutorial on how to test the Volley library with Robolectric 3.0. For example I have this get request from open weather api and need to test it.

```
public class TodayForecast extends Fragment {

public static String URL= "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?";

public static String BASE_URL= "";


String IMG_URL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/img/w/";

TextView cityText;
ImageView imageView;
private String cityName;

private String speed;
TextView countryTextView;
TextView tempTextView;
TextView windTextView;
TextView pressureTextView;
TextView humidityTextView;
TextView sunriseTextView;
TextView sunSetTextView;

private String icon;
private String retrievedLat;
private String retrievedLog;
private RequestObjects requestObjects;



public TodayForecast() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_today_forecast, container, false);

    retrievedLat = getArguments().getString("lat");
    retrievedLog = getArguments().getString("log");

    BASE_URL = URL +"lat="+retrievedLat+"&lon="+retrievedLog+"&units=metric&appid=d48708e1e4d8e2b60da14778acd8d56a";
    cityText = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.cityText);
    imageView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnailIcon);
    windTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.windTextValue);
    tempTextView = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tempText);
    pressureTextView = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.pressureTextValue);
    humidityTextView = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.humidTextValue);
    sunriseTextView = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.riseTextValue);
    sunSetTextView = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.setTextValue);
    countryTextView = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.countryText);
    //http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=39.6304951&lon=22.4206619&appid=d48708e1e4d8e2b60da14778acd8d56a

    if(savedInstanceState!=null) {
        String city_name = savedInstanceState.getString("CityName");
        String city_temp = savedInstanceState.getString("CityTemp");
        String city_pressure = savedInstanceState.getString("CityPressure");
        String city_humidity = savedInstanceState.getString("CityHumidity");
        String wind_speed = savedInstanceState.getString("WindSpeed");
        String weather_icon = savedInstanceState.getString("weatherIcon");
        String sunrise_time = savedInstanceState.getString("sunrise");
        String sunset_time = savedInstanceState.getString("sunset");
        String country_name = savedInstanceState.getString("country");

        retrievedLat = savedInstanceState.getString("lat");
        retrievedLog = savedInstanceState.getString("log");


        cityText.setText(city_name);
        tempTextView.setText(city_temp + ""+"\u00b0 \u0043");
        pressureTextView.setText(city_pressure + " hPa");
        humidityTextView.setText(city_humidity +" %");
        windTextView.setText(wind_speed+ " km/h");

        Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(weather_icon).into(imageView);

        sunriseTextView.setText(sunrise_time);
        sunSetTextView.setText(sunset_time);

        countryTextView.setText(country_name);


    }else{
         weatherData();
    }
    return rootView;
}

private void weatherData() {
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            BASE_URL,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.d("TAG", response.toString());
                    try {
                        requestObjects = new RequestObjects();

                        requestObjects.getCityName(response,cityText);

                        JSONObject main = response.getJSONObject("main");
                        requestObjects.getMainObject(main,tempTextView,humidityTextView,pressureTextView);

                        JSONObject windValue = response.getJSONObject("wind");
                        requestObjects.getWindObject(windValue,windTextView);

                        JSONObject sysJSONObject = response.getJSONObject("sys");
                        requestObjects.getSysObject(sysJSONObject,sunriseTextView,sunSetTextView,countryTextView);
                        //getSysObject(sysJSONObject);

                        JSONArray weather = response.getJSONArray("weather");
                        requestObjects.getIcon(weather,imageView);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e("TAG", e.toString());
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        }
    });
    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
}




@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    outState.putString("CityName",RequestObjects.cityName);
    outState.putString("CityTemp",RequestObjects.temperature);
    outState.putString("CityPressure",RequestObjects.pressure);
    outState.putString("CityHumidity",RequestObjects.humidity);
    outState.putString("WindSpeed",RequestObjects.speed);
    outState.putString("sunrise",RequestObjects.time);
    outState.putString("sunset",RequestObjects.setTime);
    outState.putString("weatherIcon",requestObjects.imageIcon);
    outState.putString("country",requestObjects.countryName);


  }
//If onDestroy() method is called then the fragment is not stored and the webservice will run
// again.
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.v("onDestroy","onDestroy called");
  }
```

}

I the above code,I just get info such as the temperature,the humidity and sunrise/sunset time.

Thanks

Comment: Not a tutorial, but some overview guidelines: You could use wiremock to mock requests to make sure your app behaves correctly for successful and error responses. To avoid timing/threading issues, you could replace your AppController's queue, only for tests, with an implementation which handles the requests immediately (or posts them to Robolectric's foreground or background schedulers). Without this, you may have to add sleeps in your test code, as volley has its own threading mechanism that robolectric doesn't handle.